KeyCloak page not found oauth2
why i have a "page not found" when i am redirecting to http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect
application.properties:

public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                        authorizeRequests
                                .requestMatchers("/", "/login", "/error").permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2Login(oauth2Login ->
                        oauth2Login
                                .loginPage("/login")
                                .defaultSuccessUrl("/home", true)
                );

        return http.build();
    }
}



i was trying copilot,chatgpt, find answer on stack overflow,change spring appliaction.properties,change keycloak access settings.I expect to see keycloak login page insted "page not found"

I can't tell you what exactly is wrong here but your "valid redirect uris" setting seems wrong - shouldn't /auth2 be /oauth2? Or should the redirect url rather be /auth2? - In any case the 2 urls in Keycloak and your application properties don't seem to match.
